# How can I show this list structure? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, iteration, hierarchy

'Picture a' is the data I get from the AJAX call. When a task has 'dependencyTaskId' which is equal to another task's ID, it becomes the child of that task. If 'dependencyTaskId' is null, that task will be at top level. The end results will show a tree structure of all the tasks ('picture b').

I am using Angular 6. How can I achieve this? Please help me. Thanks a lot.

[image]

[image]

```
  "orderId": 879530,
  "status": "Processing",
  "dateCreated": "2019-11-30T20:47:23.953",
  "dateCommitted": "2019-11-30T20:47:25.627",
  "dateModified": "2019-11-30T20:47:25.377",
  "coreProducts": [
    {
      "coreProductId": 1597739,
      "serviceAddress": {
        "addressId": 7506180,
        "locationId": "3472036",
        "floor": null,
        "buildingName": null,
        "flatNumber": null,
        "streetNumber": "30",
        "streetNumberSubDescription": null,
        "streetName": "LOGIE",
        "streetDirection": null,
        "suburb": "STOKES VALLEY",
        "city": "LOWER HUTT",
        "postCode": "5019",
        "freeTextAddressOverride": null,
        "attentionTo": null,
        "careOf": null,
        "addressType": "Service",
        "addressAccessInformation": null
      },
      "coreProductKey": "NGA1000/500",
      "contractLength": 12,
      "requestedDateOfProvisioning": "2019-12-07T00:00:00",
      "installationInstructions": null,
      "coreProductComponents": [
        {
          "coreProductComponentId": 2245296,
          "serviceIdentifier": "KoR157510004402",
          "service": "Internet",
          "ratePlan": "OR_access_NGA1000/500_U_Sep2019",
          "overrideCharge": 0,
          "electricityPriceOverrides": null
        }
      ],
      "coreProductCharges": null
    }
  ],
  "additionalProducts": [],
  "hardwareOrders": [
    {
      "hardwareOrderId": 1829471,
      "deliveryAddress": {
        "addressId": 7506179,
        "locationId": "3472036",
        "floor": null,
        "buildingName": null,
        "flatNumber": null,
        "streetNumber": "30",
        "streetNumberSubDescription": null,
        "streetName": "LOGIE",
        "streetDirection": null,
        "suburb": "STOKES VALLEY",
        "city": "LOWER HUTT",
        "postCode": "5019",
        "freeTextAddressOverride": null,
        "attentionTo": null,
        "careOf": null,
        "addressType": "Courier",
        "addressAccessInformation": null
      },
      "linkedServiceIdentifier": "KoR157510004402",
      "contract": null,
      "hardwareOrderItems": [
        {
          "hardwareOrderItemId": 1828173,
          "key": "NetCommNF18ACV_FIBRE_OR",
          "type": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "account": {
    "accountId": 1939814,
    "customers": [
      {
        "customerId": 1935666,
        "firstName": "CC1FE844",
        "lastName": "D007C",
        "middleName": "",
        "email": "76FC65F@gmail.com",
        "homePhoneNumber": null,
        "mobilePhoneNumber": "0212727822",
        "workPhoneNumber": null,
        "faxNumber": null,
        "dateOfBirth": "1956-03-05T00:00:00",
        "address": {
          "addressId": 7506178,
          "locationId": "3472036",
          "floor": null,
          "buildingName": null,
          "flatNumber": null,
          "streetNumber": "30",
          "streetNumberSubDescription": null,
          "streetName": "LOGIE",
          "streetDirection": null,
          "suburb": "STOKES VALLEY",
          "city": "LOWER HUTT",
          "postCode": "5019",
          "freeTextAddressOverride": null,
          "attentionTo": null,
          "careOf": null,
          "addressType": "PostalPhysical",
          "addressAccessInformation": null
        }
      }
    ],
    "organisationType": null,
    "organisationReference": null,
    "address": {
      "addressId": 7506177,
      "locationId": "3472036",
      "floor": null,
      "buildingName": null,
      "flatNumber": null,
      "streetNumber": "30",
      "streetNumberSubDescription": null,
      "streetName": "LOGIE",
      "streetDirection": null,
      "suburb": "STOKES VALLEY",
      "city": "LOWER HUTT",
      "postCode": "5019",
      "freeTextAddressOverride": null,
      "attentionTo": null,
      "careOf": null,
      "addressType": "PostalPhysical",
      "addressAccessInformation": null
    }
  },
  "losingServiceProviders": [
    {
      "losingServiceProviderId": 677663,
      "serviceIdentifier": "KoR157510004402",
      "serviceProvider": "ihug",
      "accountName": "CEDC5BFE-53EE-4319",
      "accountNumber": "20387451"
    }
  ],
  "questions": [
    {
      "questionAnswerId": 6329580,
      "question": "LiveThereOrMovingIn",
      "answer": "LiveThere",
      "serviceIdentifier": "KoR157510004402"
    },
    {
      "questionAnswerId": 6329581,
      "question": "WhatServicesCurrentlyHave",
      "answer": "BroadbandOnly",
      "serviceIdentifier": "KoR157510004402"
    }
  ],
  "promoCodes": [
    {
      "promoCodeId": 2168141,
      "promoCode": "GIGANTIC_PROMO",
      "serviceIdentifier": "KoR157510004402"
    }
  ],
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskId": 7670266,
      "name": "ChorusGatewayNGAConnectPrimary",
      "description": "Creates Chorus Gateway NGA NewConnection ticket",
      "displayName": "Chorus Gateway NGA Connect Primary",
      "dateStarted": "2019-11-30T20:47:34.617",
      "dateCompleted": null,
      "dateScheduled": null,
      "taskSource": "CoreProducts",
      "taskSourceId": "1597739",
      "dependencyTaskId": null,
      "ticketId": 36503526,
      "ticketStatus": "With Provider",
      "ticketPercentageComplete": 40,
      "externalReferenceId": null,
      "hasFailure": false,
      "failureReason": "Complete"
    },
    {
      "taskId": 7670268,
      "name": "InternetActivation",
      "description": "*InternetActivation",
      "displayName": "Internet Activation",
      "dateStarted": null,
      "dateCompleted": null,
      "dateScheduled": null,
      "taskSource": "CoreProducts",
      "taskSourceId": "1597739",
      "dependencyTaskId": 7670266,
      "ticketId": null,
      "ticketStatus": null,
      "ticketPercentageComplete": null,
      "externalReferenceId": null,
      "hasFailure": null,
      "failureReason": null
    },
    {
      "taskId": 7670271,
      "name": "InternetUsageEvaluation",
      "description": "Evaluates if the customer has internet usage",
      "displayName": "Internet Usage Evaluation",
      "dateStarted": null,
      "dateCompleted": null,
      "dateScheduled": null,
      "taskSource": "CoreProducts",
      "taskSourceId": "1597739",
      "dependencyTaskId": 7670268,
      "ticketId": null,
      "ticketStatus": null,
      "ticketPercentageComplete": null,
      "externalReferenceId": null,
      "hasFailure": null,
      "failureReason": null
    },
    {
      "taskId": 7670272,
      "name": "CustomerCoreProductInsert",
      "description": "Store LineNumber/Service data of a CoreProduct to customer tables.",
      "displayName": "Customer Core Product Insert",
      "dateStarted": null,
      "dateCompleted": null,
      "dateScheduled": null,
      "taskSource": "CoreProducts",
      "taskSourceId": "1597739",
      "dependencyTaskId": 7670268,
      "ticketId": null,
      "ticketStatus": null,
      "ticketPercentageComplete": null,
      "externalReferenceId": null,
      "hasFailure": null,
      "failureReason": null
    },
    {
      "taskId": 7670273,
      "name": "NoUsageComms",
      "description": "*NoUsageComms",
      "displayName": "No Usage Comms",
      "dateStarted": null,
      "dateCompleted": null,
      "dateScheduled": null,
      "taskSource": "CoreProducts",
      "taskSourceId": "1597739",
      "dependencyTaskId": 7670266,
      "ticketId": null,
      "ticketStatus": null,
      "ticketPercentageComplete": null,
      "externalReferenceId": null,
      "hasFailure": null,
      "failureReason": null
    },
    {
      "taskId": 7670269,
      "name": "Hardware",
      "description": "*Hardware",
      "displayName": "Order Hardware",
      "dateStarted": "2019-11-30T20:51:41.22",
      "dateCompleted": null,
      "dateScheduled": null,
      "taskSource": "HardwareOrders",
      "taskSourceId": "1828173",
      "dependencyTaskId": 7670266,
      "ticketId": 36503527,
      "ticketStatus": "Scheduled",
      "ticketPercentageComplete": 10,
      "externalReferenceId": null,
      "hasFailure": false,
      "failureReason": "Complete"
    },
    {
      "taskId": 7670270,
      "name": "PromoCode",
      "description": "Promo code task",
      "displayName": "Promo Code Task",
      "dateStarted": null,
      "dateCompleted": null,
      "dateScheduled": null,
      "taskSource": "PromoCodes",
      "taskSourceId": "2168141",
      "dependencyTaskId": 7670268,
      "ticketId": null,
      "ticketStatus": null,
      "ticketPercentageComplete": null,
      "externalReferenceId": null,
      "hasFailure": null,
      "failureReason": null
    },
    {
      "taskId": 7670267,
      "name": "SaveQuestionsAndAnswers",
      "description": "Save Questions And Answers",
      "displayName": "Save Questions And Answers",
      "dateStarted": "2019-11-30T20:47:33.307",
      "dateCompleted": "2019-11-30T20:47:33.307",
      "dateScheduled": null,
      "taskSource": "SaveQuestionsAndAnswers",
      "taskSourceId": "6329580",
      "dependencyTaskId": null,
      "ticketId": null,
      "ticketStatus": null,
      "ticketPercentageComplete": null,
      "externalReferenceId": null,
      "hasFailure": false,
      "failureReason": "Complete"
    }
  ],
  "fulfilmentItems": []
}
```

Comment: do you have control over this API? if yes then I would suggest you prepare JSON data on the server as parent and child so in the front end you don't need to do all the stuff

Comment: you need a recursive function

Comment: I do. From my understanding, this kind of manipulation is good to happen at the frontend. Correct me if I’m wrong. Cheers

Comment: Can you share the json data?

Comment: @hbamithkumara. Json is added to the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must try this via frontend side:

```
const apiResponse = {"orderId": 879530, "status": "Processing", "dateCreated": "2019-11-30T20:47:23.953", "dateCommitted": "2019-11-30T20:47:25.627", "dateModified": "2019-11-30T20:47:25.377", "coreProducts": [ { "coreProductId": 1597739, "serviceAddress": { "addressId": 7506180, "locationId": "3472036", "floor": null, "buildingName": null, "flatNumber": null, "streetNumber": "30", "streetNumberSubDescription": null, "streetName": "LOGIE", "streetDirection": null, "suburb": "STOKES VALLEY", "city": "LOWER HUTT", "postCode": "5019", "freeTextAddressOverride": null, "attentionTo": null, "careOf": null, "addressType": "Service", "addressAccessInformation": null }, "coreProductKey": "NGA1000/500", "contractLength": 12, "requestedDateOfProvisioning": "2019-12-07T00:00:00", "installationInstructions": null, "coreProductComponents": [ { "coreProductComponentId": 2245296, "serviceIdentifier": "KoR157510004402", "service": "Internet", "ratePlan": "OR_access_NGA1000/500_U_Sep2019", "overrideCharge": 0, "electricityPriceOverrides": null } ], "coreProductCharges": null } ], "additionalProducts": [], "hardwareOrders": [ { "hardwareOrderId": 1829471, "deliveryAddress": { "addressId": 7506179, "locationId": "3472036", "floor": null, "buildingName": null, "flatNumber": null, "streetNumber": "30", "streetNumberSubDescription": null, "streetName": "LOGIE", "streetDirection": null, "suburb": "STOKES VALLEY", "city": "LOWER HUTT", "postCode": "5019", "freeTextAddressOverride": null, "attentionTo": null, "careOf": null, "addressType": "Courier", "addressAccessInformation": null }, "linkedServiceIdentifier": "KoR157510004402", "contract": null, "hardwareOrderItems": [ { "hardwareOrderItemId": 1828173, "key": "NetCommNF18ACV_FIBRE_OR", "type": null } ] } ], "account": { "accountId": 1939814, "customers": [ { "customerId": 1935666, "firstName": "CC1FE844", "lastName": "D007C", "middleName": "", "email": "76FC65F@gmail.com", "homePhoneNumber": null, "mobilePhoneNumber": "0212727822", "workPhoneNumber": null, "faxNumber": null, "dateOfBirth": "1956-03-05T00:00:00", "address": { "addressId": 7506178, "locationId": "3472036", "floor": null, "buildingName": null, "flatNumber": null, "streetNumber": "30", "streetNumberSubDescription": null, "streetName": "LOGIE", "streetDirection": null, "suburb": "STOKES VALLEY", "city": "LOWER HUTT", "postCode": "5019", "freeTextAddressOverride": null, "attentionTo": null, "careOf": null, "addressType": "PostalPhysical", "addressAccessInformation": null } } ], "organisationType": null, "organisationReference": null, "address": { "addressId": 7506177, "locationId": "3472036", "floor": null, "buildingName": null, "flatNumber": null, "streetNumber": "30", "streetNumberSubDescription": null, "streetName": "LOGIE", "streetDirection": null, "suburb": "STOKES VALLEY", "city": "LOWER HUTT", "postCode": "5019", "freeTextAddressOverride": null, "attentionTo": null, "careOf": null, "addressType": "PostalPhysical", "addressAccessInformation": null } }, "losingServiceProviders": [ { "losingServiceProviderId": 677663, "serviceIdentifier": "KoR157510004402", "serviceProvider": "ihug", "accountName": "CEDC5BFE-53EE-4319", "accountNumber": "20387451" } ], "questions": [ { "questionAnswerId": 6329580, "question": "LiveThereOrMovingIn", "answer": "LiveThere", "serviceIdentifier": "KoR157510004402" }, { "questionAnswerId": 6329581, "question": "WhatServicesCurrentlyHave", "answer": "BroadbandOnly", "serviceIdentifier": "KoR157510004402" } ], "promoCodes": [ { "promoCodeId": 2168141, "promoCode": "GIGANTIC_PROMO", "serviceIdentifier": "KoR157510004402" } ], "tasks": [ { "taskId": 7670266, "name": "ChorusGatewayNGAConnectPrimary", "description": "Creates Chorus Gateway NGA NewConnection ticket", "displayName": "Chorus Gateway NGA Connect Primary", "dateStarted": "2019-11-30T20:47:34.617", "dateCompleted": null, "dateScheduled": null, "taskSource": "CoreProducts", "taskSourceId": "1597739", "dependencyTaskId": null, "ticketId": 36503526, "ticketStatus": "With Provider", "ticketPercentageComplete": 40, "externalReferenceId": null, "hasFailure": false, "failureReason": "Complete" }, { "taskId": 7670268, "name": "InternetActivation", "description": "*InternetActivation", "displayName": "Internet Activation", "dateStarted": null, "dateCompleted": null, "dateScheduled": null, "taskSource": "CoreProducts", "taskSourceId": "1597739", "dependencyTaskId": 7670266, "ticketId": null, "ticketStatus": null, "ticketPercentageComplete": null, "externalReferenceId": null, "hasFailure": null, "failureReason": null }, { "taskId": 7670271, "name": "InternetUsageEvaluation", "description": "Evaluates if the customer has internet usage", "displayName": "Internet Usage Evaluation", "dateStarted": null, "dateCompleted": null, "dateScheduled": null, "taskSource": "CoreProducts", "taskSourceId": "1597739", "dependencyTaskId": 7670268, "ticketId": null, "ticketStatus": null, "ticketPercentageComplete": null, "externalReferenceId": null, "hasFailure": null, "failureReason": null }, { "taskId": 7670272, "name": "CustomerCoreProductInsert", "description": "Store LineNumber/Service data of a CoreProduct to customer tables.", "displayName": "Customer Core Product Insert", "dateStarted": null, "dateCompleted": null, "dateScheduled": null, "taskSource": "CoreProducts", "taskSourceId": "1597739", "dependencyTaskId": 7670268, "ticketId": null, "ticketStatus": null, "ticketPercentageComplete": null, "externalReferenceId": null, "hasFailure": null, "failureReason": null }, { "taskId": 7670273, "name": "NoUsageComms", "description": "*NoUsageComms", "displayName": "No Usage Comms", "dateStarted": null, "dateCompleted": null, "dateScheduled": null, "taskSource": "CoreProducts", "taskSourceId": "1597739", "dependencyTaskId": 7670266, "ticketId": null, "ticketStatus": null, "ticketPercentageComplete": null, "externalReferenceId": null, "hasFailure": null, "failureReason": null }, { "taskId": 7670269, "name": "Hardware", "description": "*Hardware", "displayName": "Order Hardware", "dateStarted": "2019-11-30T20:51:41.22", "dateCompleted": null, "dateScheduled": null, "taskSource": "HardwareOrders", "taskSourceId": "1828173", "dependencyTaskId": 7670266, "ticketId": 36503527, "ticketStatus": "Scheduled", "ticketPercentageComplete": 10, "externalReferenceId": null, "hasFailure": false, "failureReason": "Complete" }, { "taskId": 7670270, "name": "PromoCode", "description": "Promo code task", "displayName": "Promo Code Task", "dateStarted": null, "dateCompleted": null, "dateScheduled": null, "taskSource": "PromoCodes", "taskSourceId": "2168141", "dependencyTaskId": 7670268, "ticketId": null, "ticketStatus": null, "ticketPercentageComplete": null, "externalReferenceId": null, "hasFailure": null, "failureReason": null }, { "taskId": 7670267, "name": "SaveQuestionsAndAnswers", "description": "Save Questions And Answers", "displayName": "Save Questions And Answers", "dateStarted": "2019-11-30T20:47:33.307", "dateCompleted": "2019-11-30T20:47:33.307", "dateScheduled": null, "taskSource": "SaveQuestionsAndAnswers", "taskSourceId": "6329580", "dependencyTaskId": null, "ticketId": null, "ticketStatus": null, "ticketPercentageComplete": null, "externalReferenceId": null, "hasFailure": false, "failureReason": "Complete" } ], "fulfilmentItems": [] }

const nestedChild = (inputArray, parentKeyName, childKeyName, relationKeyValue = null) => {
    const tree = []
    for(let i in inputArray) {
        if(inputArray[i][childKeyName] == relationKeyValue) {
            let children = nestedChild(inputArray, parentKeyName, childKeyName, inputArray[i][parentKeyName])

            if(children.length) {
                inputArray[i].children = children
            }
            tree.push(inputArray[i])
        }
    }
    return tree
}



apiResponse.tasks = nestedChild(
  apiResponse.tasks, 
  'taskId',
  'dependencyTaskId',
  null
);

console.log(apiResponse);
```

Output: 
[image]

Now you can traverse and print it in unordered list and can format it via css.

Hope this will help you much.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I’m wondering if this solution works on multi level nesting? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, it will work for multi-level nested items as well.

Comment: I had a try today but it didn’t seem to work. It always returns empty array.

Comment: Hi @Mark, I have updated the code, I have converted es5 to es6 and did a mistake, I have rectified it and updated it as well. If still doesn't work then please share sample JSON data.

Comment: @ Aman, thanks for your update but it still doesn't work. Json is added to the question.

Comment: Hi @Mark, I believe, this is complete solution that I was discussion earlier. Please check and enjoy with it. Let me know if still facing any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [angular-tree-component](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/getting-started) to show the tasks.

In order to use this component you will have to turn your flat task array into a tree of nodes where each node contains a reference to it's child nodes. This can be done using a simple recursive function.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tree-component-u3gmlp-r9hqpg

(You may want to configure it to look more like the screenshot you have provided)